# OS for Docker Image - Flavors

Tags: linux, docker

I'm very curious if most people are simply using Ubuntu for the majority of Linux flavors out there for their Docker images or if they're using others.  Can you tell me if you are using Ubuntu and if not why..and what else are you using?

Is Ubuntu the defacto flavor just in general?

Comment: I think the question is best suited for http://superuser.com Also people use those OS images which well they need, be it RedHat or one of its derivatives, spin-offs etc, Debian & Co including Ubuntu, even Arch or Gentoo. What particular problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many people use the same OS in their containers they are used to using on servers and VPSes, thus the popular ones: Ubuntu, Debian, Red Hat, Centos. This provides familiarity but generally is much larger than necessary. This is not necessarily a well-informed technical decision as it is an empirical reality.

Once people realize Ubuntu and Red Hat are much bigger than needed in a container, they start choosing Debian more as it's smaller, and when they get more hardcore about this start looking at Alpine Linux or going to unikernel type images.

Comment: thanks exactly what I was wondering...appreciate the response